# How to load a .stan file from Github in R

Tags: r, github, jupyter-notebook, stan

I'm writing a tutorial on STAN in Jupyter Notebook for use on Google Collaboratory. I have all of the project files on Github (the data, model code, results..) and I need to load the STAN model from Github. Within this notebook I am using R language and cmdstanr package. I first load rpy2 to run R within the .ipynb

```
    %load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

And also to load the package cmdstanr:

```
    %%R 
    library(cmdstanr)
```

So what DOES WORK is manually uploading the file into Google Collaboratory and then loading it:

```
    %%R
    setwd('my_dir')
    file <- file.path("MyModel.stan")
    MyModel <- cmdstan_model(file)
    MyModel$print()
```

What DOES NOT WORK is loading the file in Github.. Here is what I've tried:

```
    %%R 
    MyModel_URL <- url("https://github.com/laurabustamante/individual_differences_analysis_stan/blob/main/TwoStep_ITC_covar.stan?raw=true") 
    MyModel_txt <- readLines(MyModel_URL)
    MyModel <- cmdstan_model(MyModel_txt)
```

I get the error:

> R[write to console]: Error in initialize(...) :    Assertion on
> 'stan_file' failed: File does not exist: '// simultaneous fit model
> for Two-step Task and Intertemporal Choice Task'.
>
> R[write to console]: In addition:  R[write to console]: Warning
> message:
>
> R[write to console]: In readLines(TwoStep_ITC_covar_stan_URL) :
> R[write to console]:    R[write to console]:  incomplete final line
> found on
> 'https://github.com/laurabustamante/individual_differences_analysis_stan/blob/main/TwoStep_ITC_covar.stan?raw=true'

I've tried a number of other things but I don't think any of them are closer to the solution. I searched the web and can't seem to find anything.

Another note, I have been able to load an .RDS from Github in the same notebook using this code:

```
    %%R
    ITC_con <- gzcon(url("https://github.com/IanEisenberg/Self_Regulation_Ontology/blob/master/Data/Complete_02-16-2019/Individual_Measures/discount_titrate.csv.gz?raw=true"))
    ITC_txt <- readLines(ITC_con)
    ITC_data_full <- read.csv(textConnection(ITC_txt))
```

Thanks for you ideas!

Comment: can you try without `?raw=true` extension ? I mean `MyModel_URL <- url("https://github.com/laurabustamante/individual_differences_analysis_stan/blob/main/TwoStep_ITC_covar.stan") `

Comment: Looks like `MyModel_txt` contains the stan code as a string, rather than as a filename. And it looks like `cmdstan_model()` needs a filename. You might be able to use `write_stan_file()` to create a temp file and bridge the gap (see https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/reference/write_stan_file.html)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Hobo for a successful suggestion! This code works:

```
MyModel_URL <- url("https://github.com/laurabustamante/individual_differences_analysis_stan/blob/main/TwoStep_ITC_covar.stan?raw=true")
MyModel_txt <- readLines(MyModel_URL)
MyModel_tmpf <- write_stan_file(MyModel_txt)
MyModel <- cmdstan_model(MyModel_tmpf)
```

It turned out that having ?raw=true you get the meta-data from Github and that doesn't work.

Comment: Cool; glad it worked.  Hadn't used the package, so wasn't certain